# Computing conditional variance

Tags: r, variance

Is there a package in R that does that?

How could I compute the conditional variance $\mathrm{var}(y|x)$ of a sample?

I also don't know what to do in case where there are not enough $y$ for each $x$.
Variance exists but for close $x$, so each $x$ gets only one value hence 
$\mathrm{var}(y|x) = 0$.

Comment: Unless you have fairly large samples at each $x$, you have to make some assumptions. How does y relate to x?

Comment: Hi Glen, thankx for the response. No, I don't make any assumptions I don't know how y relates to x. I thought of grouping together x using quantiles for instance.or maybe some king of bootstrapping. still searching insights/solutions.

Comment: So ... not even an assumption like $E(Y|X)$ is a smooth function of $x$?

Comment: Hi Glen,No.In fact i'm trying to avoid this assumption.

Answer (score 4):

In a regression setting, this can be done by first fitting a regression model to the data, and then fitting a second regression model, where the response variable is the squared residuals of the first model.  This works because regression is a method of estimating the conditional mean of the data, and the conditional mean of the squared distance from the mean (i.e. the residuals) *is* the conditional variance.  This method will result in a biased estimate of the variance (it will be smaller than the true value) because we have estimated the conditional mean from the data.  One possible solution is to fit the second model to the squared leave-one-out residuals of the first model.

Alternatively, you can perform a maximum-likelihood model of both the conditional variance and conditional mean at the same time, but I don't know of any R code for that.

I wrote (with co-authors) a paper on this in a non-linear regression setting a few years back, which may be of some use:

G. C. Cawley, N. L. C. Talbot, R. J. Foxall, S. R. Dorling and D. P. Mandic, Heteroscedastic kernel ridge regression, Neurocomputing, vol. 57, pp 105-124, March 2004. ([doi](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231204000621), [preprint](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/publications/pdf/neurocomp2004a.pdf))

It seems a fairly obvious approach, so I suspect it may have been done before in a different setting.

Comment: Hi,thankx dircan. I need to look at the paper. but in order to do regression, don't i need to know what type of regression?    I cannot assume linearity.                                  I need to look more into it.your paper and there is sandwich method or robust residual regression packages.

Comment: Hey  @Dikran, I'm working on a similar thing and I would like to ask you a question. When I run my first regression, I take the squared residuals as target and my X as input again and then after running the second regression how can I get the conditional variance of my first target conditionally to my X ?